# Emacs Giving Error on Using Color Themes

Tags: emacs

Here's the error I'm getting - Windows install, color-theme.el and themes installed.

```
Color-theme-backup-original-values: Symbol’s function definition is void: color-theme-
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was/is that color-theme.el expects to have the themes in a folder one below where it resides, in a directory called "themes". That solved it.